# How to run iisexpress in the background without blocking script?

Tags: windows, powershell, iis-express, appveyor

I am currently trying to run iisexpress during appveyor build in order to run integration tests. However the script gets blocked at `start /wait iisexpress /path:%APPVEYOR_BUILD_FOLDER% /port:%iis_port%`. My windows scripting skills are not as good as I hoped and google has not been friendly so far. Here is the concerned bit of the script below:

```
cd \Program Files\IIS Express

start /wait iisexpress /path:%APPVEYOR_BUILD_FOLDER% /port:%iis_port%

echo "Start operations"
```

Here is a capture of where the script blocks

[image]
<sub>(source: [iamnguele.com](http://www.iamnguele.com/img/stackoverflow_iisexpress_issue.png))</sub>

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was the issue, actually I needed to add the parameter `-PassThru` to have the process running in the background.

Here is my updated code:

```
cd \Program Files\IIS Express

start /wait iisexpress /path:%APPVEYOR_BUILD_FOLDER% /port:%iis_port% -PassThru

echo "Start operations"
```

And the new result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to remove `/wait` as it blocks build pipeline waiting for iisexpress to stop, but nobody there to stop it.

Note that in AppVeyor you can always troubleshoot this type of issues with [RDP connection to build worker](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/rdp-to-build-worker).

Thank you,

Ilya.

Comment: The thing is that I try to have iisexpress to run until I can make some calls and kill it later, without blocking the background.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to kill it later? AppVeyor creates fresh VM for every build and kill whole VM after build is done so your iisexpress process will not survive for long anyway :)

Comment: I want to run some integration tests so I still need iisexpress not to block the process ^^ If I don't have to kill it things get easier