# How to run iisexpress in background

Tags: windows, asp.net-core, batch-file, iis-express

I am trying to run my asp.net core web app on iisexpress using a batch file. Here is the content of the batch file:

> SET ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development SET
> LAUNCHER_PATH=C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\myapp\bin\x64\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\myapp.exe
> cd /d "C:\Program Files\IIS Express" iisexpress.exe
> /config:"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\myapp.vs\myapp\config\applicationhost.config"
> /site:"myapp" /apppool:"myapp AppPool"

This batch script successfully starting my app on IIS Express, but it is running in the foreground, with a command prompt open having the application logs in it.
How can I run my application in the background so that I don't have to face the command prompt

I've tried one of the solution given in
[How to run iisexpress in the background without blocking script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40129259/how-to-run-iisexpress-in-the-background-without-blocking-script)

And made changes in the command:

> start /wait iisexpress.exe
> /config:"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\myapp.vs\myapp\config\applicationhost.config"
> /site:"myapp" /apppool:"myapp AppPool" -PassThru

With this, my script is executed in the background, but I can't see the IIS Express process running in my process details(application is not running)

Comment: If you're only running one command, then you don't need to `/wait` for it to finish. Also you could take a look at the help/usage information by opening a Command Prompt window, typing `start /?`, and pressing the `[ENTER]` key. In addition, why are you using the Command Prompt, to run an exectuable file?

Comment: I'm running a batch script using the command prompt, which has all the commands which I've mentioned above

Comment: To begin with, your question requires revisiting because you've not formatted it in a way that end users can read your code, (which you've decided to post as quoted text). In the upper version you have, what I assume to be four commands, the first two are unrelated to the others, and have little purpose, because the `SET` command defines variables locally, not globally. The second two could easily be merged into a one line command. Also, `iisexpress.exe` is just an independent application which accepts arguments, there is no need whatsoever to run it in a batch file, or Command Prompt window.